# Is it profitable for a miner to manipulate blocks in a small Ethereum project?

Tags: solidity, security, randomness, vulnerability, blockhash

In the context of my blockchain project, I’m using the `blockhash()` function to generate randomness. However, I’m concerned about the potential vulnerability of this method. I’d like to know if, in a small project with limited volume, it would truly be profitable for a miner to manipulate `blockhash` to predict outcomes, despite the known security flaw. What factors should be considered in evaluating the risks and costs associated with such attacks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect your contract to ever hold any significant amount of value, then you are probably okay to go against best practice and use pseudorandomness.

However, even if there is a small chance that a real value can be obtained by bypassing a function that uses pseudorandomness, you should definitely consider using an Oracle instead.

Chainlink's [VRF](https://docs.chain.link/vrf) is an easy way to get true random numbers inside your smart contract.

All it takes for a malicious user to calculate the same pseudorandom number as your contract, is to literally use the same variables you do when calculating it.

For example if you have this function in your contract:

```js
contract YourContract {
    function pseudoRandom(bytes32 key) public view returns(bool){
        if(key != keccak256(abi.encode(blockhash(block.number)))) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

All it takes for another user to get returned true is this:

```js
contract MaliciousEntity {

    YourContract public a;
    constructor(address _a)  {
        a = YourContract(_a);
    }
    function bypass() external view returns(bool){
        return a.pseudoRandom(keccak256(abi.encode(blockhash(block.number))));
    }
}
```

Also to clarify, `miners` no longer exist on Ethereum now that it has switched to Proof-of-Stake as opposed to the original Proof-of-work consensus, you can read more about that [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pos/).

The `blockhash()` method simply returns the "*hash of the given block when blocknumber is one of the 256 most recent blocks; otherwise returns zero*". You can read about it in the Solidity docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.22/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties).